# Regardless of the size this figure takes a whole page

Tags: subfig, figure-placement

Regardless of the size this double figure takes a whole page, is there a way to prevent this behavior?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
%\begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\scalebox{0.1}{
\includesvg{dia/layouts/1.svg}
}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\scalebox{0.13}{
\includesvg{dia/layouts/2.svg}
}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Left: a caption for the left side, Right: a caption for the right side}
\label{fig:long}
%\end{adjustwidth}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: we can not run your example, and it's a single figure so one page?

Comment: its a double figure in one figure , 2 svg files
feel free and replace with whaterver, I already tried every size file, and changed the settings of scalebox to small, big, removed it even but this double figure always specify a whole page,

Comment: You need to have some text tho to see what I mean

Comment: it is your responsiblity to make an example that shows your problem (you can use `example-image`)

Comment: `\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}` makes each subfigure take half the page.  You say that you've been adjusting the scale box (which can be more easily done with `\includegraphics[scale=??]` or better `\includegraphics[width=??]`), but have you adjusted the argument to `{subfigure}`?

Comment: I'm trying to use SVG

Comment: sorry David this example-image didn't work with SVG

Comment: you get `! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.9 \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}` as that is not the syntax of the obsolete subfigure package so I get no output, even if I guess how you defined `\includesvg` and `\scalebox` which are not defined in your example

Comment: that's true, Im checking it on an empty project, it doesn't work but on my own project it wroks, not sure what's the problem, I will update you

Comment: that's why you should always post a complete test document, if you  post code unrelated to the issue it is very hard to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You loaded the obsolete `subfigure` package but used the syntax of `subcaption`, and used `\includesvg` and `\scalebox` with no definition.

If I fix those and just use a `\rule` rather than an svg to simplify the example, the figure is set as a top float as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\scalebox{0.1}{%
\rule{10cm}{10cm}%\includesvg{exmple-image.svg}%
}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\scalebox{0.13}{%
\rule{10cm}{10cm}%\includesvg{example-image.svg}%
}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Left: a caption for the left side, Right: a caption for the right side}
\label{fig:long}

\end{figure}

AaAAA BBBB CCCC AaAAA BBBB CCCC AaAAA BBBB CCCC
AaAAA BBBB CCCC AaAAA BBBB CCCC AaAAA BBBB CCCC
AaAAA BBBB CCCC AaAAA BBBB CCCC AaAAA BBBB CCCC
AaAAA BBBB CCCC AaAAA BBBB CCCC AaAAA BBBB CCCC
AaAAA BBBB CCCC AaAAA BBBB CCCC AaAAA BBBB CCCC
AaAAA BBBB CCCC AaAAA BBBB CCCC AaAAA BBBB CCCC

 
\end{document}
```

Comment: it should be SVG but thanks, with SVG it doesn't work they way you described

Comment: @KamranAsgari the placement of a figure is completely unaffected by the content, apart from its size, so if the svg are that size it would work as shown, obviously if they are bigger the figure could take a whole page.

Comment: The thing is for the other figure, I export two svg in one file so It was just one figure and that one doesn't have a problem, but anyway I will accept this answer although I'm not using it, thank you :)

Comment: @KamranAsgari if  you post code that can never produce output, and ask questions about a document you have not shown, then people helping have to make a lot of guesses. If the figure takes a whole page then it is bigger than 70% of the page and so not allowed by default as a top float,so making the content smaller will solve your issue,